# git plumbing command to get submodule remote

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-plumbing

I am working with git plumbing and mirrored (and thus bare) repos, in a readonly filesystem.

I can see the existence of submodules with `git ls-tree`. I can infer their name/path and the SHA1, but I can't find a way to get the submodule remote.

The information is in there somewhere; if I clone the repo, `git submodule init` succeeds. (Making a clone is too expensive for normal use, particularly for very large repositories.) How can I get at the submodule remote directly?

Comment: It's in the `.gitmodules` file which has config-file format, so if you extract the file you can use `git config -f` (aka `--file`) on it. This is itself a bit tricky though. `git show <rev>:.gitmodules` or `git cat-file -p <rev>:.gitmodules` will get the contents. If you have `/dev/stdin` you can pipe those to `git config -f /dev/stdin`.

Comment: @torek will you turn this into an answer, so that I can accept it? That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I can, but I'm not sure off-hand what you need to extract from the `.gitmodules` file (i.e., what it is you need to `git config -f ... --get`.

Comment: That's fine. The key piece was knowing where the data was hidden. Figuring out the format is easy. :) Looks like you search for `submodule.<name>.path=<path>` where <path> is the path you want to match. That tells you <name>. Then look up `submodule.<name>.url=<url>` and you're all set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Summary

Start with `git config --blob HEAD:.gitmodules --list` and go from there.  This requires Git versions >= 1.8.4.  Note that `HEAD` can be any revision.

#### Long form and explanation

Comments turned into answer, with much of the answer provided by the OP. :-) Also, we have the following self-referential definitions: a *superproject* is a Git repository that has submodules, and a *submodule* (sometimes also called a *subproject*) is a Git repository controlled by a superproject.  The submodule itself is normally kept checked-out at a specific commit (i.e., as a "detached HEAD"), although there are now special cases where you can direct Git to switch a submodule to a named branch.  If a submodule has further submodules, the "outer" submodule is a superproject for the "inner" submodule, so super/sub is all relative.

The submodules—the repository URLs and their checkout paths—are provided by a file named `.gitmodules` in the root directory of the superproject.  Hence in a bare repository, you would obtain or extract the `.gitmodules` file.  This file is formatted as a config file, so it is readable via `git config --file`.

Since Git version 2.0, you can use the pseudo-name `-` to refer to stdin, so:

```
git show HEAD:.gitmodules | git config --file - --list
```

will dump the contents in a familiar format.  (If your Git variant is older than that, but you have `/dev/stdin`, you can read `/dev/stdin` here.)

It turns out that there is an even easier way, though: `git config` can, since Git version 1.8.4, read a blob straight out of the repository.  The blob identifier is anything acceptable to `git rev-parse`, which can handle not only a branch name or commit ID, but even a subsequent path name.  (This code went in specifically for submodule handling: see [commit 1bc888193e1044db317a45b9a4c8d2b87b998f40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bc888193e1044db317a45b9a4c8d2b87b998f40).)

#### Details

Given a submodule path *P*, the name of the submodule is whichever entry has `submodule.name.path` set to *P*.  The URL for that submodule is then `submodule.name.url`.

It's possible to search out the desired name using `git config --get-regexp`.  However, it's annoying at best since we must then quote pathname components that are regular expression meta-characters, with the obvious common one being `.`:

```
$ git config --blob HEAD:.gitmodules \
    --get-regexp 'submodule\..*\.path' 'some/dir\.name/path'
submodule.foo.path some/dir.name/path
```

so it probably makes more sense just to dump out the configuration with `--list` and use something else to extract the interesting fields.  For instance:

```
git config --blob HEAD:.gitmodules --list | \
    awk -F= -vpath='some/dir.name/path' \
    '$1 ~ /submodule\..*\.path/ && $2 == path { split($1, a, "."); print a[2] }'
```

(although by the time you put this into something that can read trees looking for gitlinks, you probably want Python or some such).

Answer (score 0):

Since git v2.x you can use the following:

```sh
git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp 'submodule\.\S+\.path' | 
    awk '{print $2}' |
    xargs -i git -C {} remote get-url origin
```

#### Explanation

- 1st and 2nd commands return relative paths of all submodules
- 3rd command executes `git remote` inside submodules' directories and gets url of their origin

#### NB

- remote names for submodules should be "origin" (set by git as default remote name)
- submodules should already be initialized before (eg. by executing `git submodule update --init` inside superproject)